# Change placeholderText default TextColor for NSTextField

Tags: nstextfield

I am trying to change the placeholderText for `NSTextField`, I am able to set the place holder text but the default color for text is black and I need to change that color. Can someone please guide me as in how to proceed?

Here is my code:

```
NSString* defaultText = [[NSString alloc] defaultText.c_str() defaultText.length()];
[[textField cell] setPlaceholderString:defaultText];
```

How to change the color of `defaultText`?

Comment: @Feras *"briefly explain"* is **not** an appropriate description of your changes, stop using it. Say what you're actually editing.

Comment: Try `placeholderAttributedString` of the text field.

Comment: Yes It worked ...Thanks a  Lot !!!! :)